# Moving files to different directories

Tags: bash, scripts

I'm trying to move media and other files which are in a specified directory to another directory, which will be created if it does not exist. And, I'm trying to create a directory where the remaining files with different extensions will go. My first problem is that my script is not making a new directory and it is not moving the files to other directories. How can I move files with different extensions to one directory?

This is what i have had so far. Please correct me where I'm wrong and help modify my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
From=/home/katy/doc
To=/home/katy/mo #directory where the media files will go
WA=/home/katy/do # directory where the other files will go
 if [ ! -d "$To" ]; then
   mkdir -p "$To"
 fi
cd $From
find . -type f -name"*.mp4" -exec mv {} $To \;
```

Comment: A better place for this question would be [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Call this script with the extensions you want to move.
# E.g.,     ./script mp4 avi flv
From="/home/katy/doc"
To="/home/katy/mo" #directory where the media files will go
WA="/home/katy/do" # directory where the other files will go
 if [[ ! -d "$To" ]]; then
   mkdir -p "$To"
 fi
cd "$From"
for i in "$@"; do # You could also hard code this: for i in mp3 mp4 avi; do
  find . -type f -name "*.${i}" -exec mv "{}" "$To" \;
done
```

{ and } are special characters. I think that adding a bunch of quotes to your script will help make it clearer and work better.

Comment: thanks its working though im stack on one thing how can i move file like .mp3,.mp4.avi to the same folder using one command or using the same script

Comment: hey scott i need a favour again on this same script i want to modify so that it parses parameters,My first problem is that I want when I put -d and full path on the terminal it should move only media files, -l and full path to move all text files, then -x to change the extension to uppercase, then -u to lowercase.

Comment: -m path    Move media files
-t path    Move text files
-u         Change extensions to upper-case
-l         Change extensions to lower-case

Comment: I suggest you read up on getopt. Or better yet, switch languages to something like Ruby or Python, as this is more complex than I like to do in Bash. Also, remember that you'll have to use functions for something like this. I don't have time to write the code for you, as it'll take significantly more code, but I'm willing to help you debug the code you write.

Comment: im going to post a new thread then check it out if it will make sense.